# Python code to iterate through ascending numerical values in one column of a pandas dataframe, and print the missing numbers

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a pandas dataframe where one column is an ID that falls between 1 and 900. I'm trying to using python to iterate through the rows, and return the missing ID numbers.

For instance, the ID column in the first four rows has the following values:

3
6
7
9
10

I want a code that would return the missing numbers in that ascending sequence:

1
2
4
5
8

I know I need to use some sort of loop, but I'm not sure how to structure it.

I looked for examples of this kind of application using iterrows, and couldn't find anything that matches this use case. I'm new to programming, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why in your example is the number `3`stated as missing? What about number `8`?

Comment: Sorry, silly error on my end. I just corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.setdiff1d` to get the missing numbers:

```py
out = np.setdiff1d(np.arange(1, df.col1.max() + 1), df.col1, assume_unique=True)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[1 2 4 5 8]
```

---

Input `df`:

```
   col1
0     3
1     6
2     7
3     9
4    10
```

---

Or: Using `set.difference`:

```py
out = set(range(1, df.col1.max() + 1)).difference(df.col1)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{1, 2, 4, 5, 8}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'ID': [3, 6, 7, 9, 10]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
data2 = {'Num': range(1, df1.ID.max()+1)}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
missing_numbers = df2[~df2['Num'].isin(df1['ID'])]
print("Missing Nums:")
print(missing_numbers['Num'].tolist())
```